# Swapping columns in certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame like this:

```
     A            B      C
"010-1"       "Car"     500
"010-2"     "Train"     302
"Result"      "010"      23
"011-1"      "Ship"     321
"011-2"     "Plane"     321
"011-3"      "Bike"     321
"Result"      "011"     321
```

Now is it possible to shift columns `A` and `B` in rows where the `"Result"` value is in column `A` using Pandas?

So that end result is:

```
     A            B       C
"010-1"       "Car"     500
"010-2"     "Train"     302
  "010"     "Result"     23
"011-1"      "Ship"     321
"011-2"     "Plane"     321
"011-3"      "Bike"     321
  "011"    "Result"     321
```

EDIT: Acutally there might be more columns than one apart from A and B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the numpy function `where()`:

Original dataframe:

```
In[6]: df
Out[6]: 
        A      B    C
0   010-1    Car  500
1   010-2  Train  302
2  Result    010   23
3   011-1   Ship  321
4   011-2  Plane  321
5   011-3   Bike  321
6  Result    011  321
```

---

**Commands:**
(using common Python pattern `x, y = y, x` for switching values)

```
In[7]: cond = df.A == "Result"
In[8]: df.A, df.B = np.where(cond, df.B, df.A), np.where(cond, df.A, df.B)
```

---

Result:

```
In[9]: df
Out[9]: 
       A       B    C
0  010-1     Car  500
1  010-2   Train  302
2    010  Result   23
3  011-1    Ship  321
4  011-2   Plane  321
5  011-3    Bike  321
6    011  Result  321
```

Answer (score 1):

Long hand use np.where

```
m=df['A'].str.contains('"Result"')
df['b']=df['B']
df['B']=np.where(m,df['A'], df['B'])
df['C']=np.where(m,df['b'], df['C'])
df.drop(columns=['b'], inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm what if there are more columns apart from column A B? Like not only C but more than one?

Comment: Missed your question then. Thats not what you asked first time though

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df['A'],df['B'] =df['A'].combine(df['B'],lambda x,y : [x,y] if x != 'Result' else [y,x]).str
```

Comment: Ingenious use of `.str` to obtain a pair of series from the series of pairs. +1.